# Limit ENI permissions for VPC-Enabled Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a role policy, used by an AWS Lambda, which contains the [execution permissions which allow the Lambda to be VPC-enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html).  In other words, it has these permissions:

```
    "Sid": "VPCEnabledLambda",
    "Action": [
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
      "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "*"
```

The above works.  However, aside from the ENI's implicitly needed by the VPC-enabled lambda, I would like to "tighten" these permissions so that the Lambda could never *explicitly* create or delete arbitrary ENI's.  What kind of `Condition` could I add to achieve this?

I'm suspicious that what I'm asking isn't possible, but I want to be sure.

One idea I have is to have a condition that targets the "Description" of the ENI's in question.  All the ENI's implicitly created/deleted by the Lambda would have a description that begins with "AWS Lambda VPC ENI".  However, that might be useful as a condition only when deleting an ENI.  I'm not sure.  If it were possible to tighten this, I'm not sure what other condition keys to explore. Perhaps `ec2:Subnet` could help limit the permissions to the subnet used by the Lambda's implicit ENI's?

What options do I have?

Comment: When you say "Lambda could never explicitly create or delete arbitrary ENI's" are you referring to your own code inside the Lambda function?

Comment: @JorgeGarcia Yes.  I don't want a developer / maintainer of this function using the AWS SDK to provision or de-provision ENI's that are no business of the Lambda.